# AVAudioPlayer- play from sound buffer

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I've been looking at using AVAudioPlayer to play sounds. The problem here is the format- I have a bunch of WAV samples in a buffer but no WAV header at all. AVAudioPlayer doesn't seem to allow you to just set the format, it has to try to interpret it from the NSData buffer. Having to copy over the entire sound before it can start playing is not going to be a good experience for my users.

If I have a buffer of WAV samples (*not* a WAV file in memory), how can I play it back with AVAudioPlayer without crippling my performance with a gigantic copy?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the entire (gigantic) sound, just copy a WAV file header in front the first sample of the existing buffer.  When initially obtaining your wave data into memory (file load, download, or synthesis, etc.), make sure there is at least 44 bytes of padding in front, so there's room to copy the header in.  If it's a buffer snippet, save a bit of the data, copy the WAV header in, play the sound, and then restore the original 44 bytes.